# measure distance between patches in circle

Tags: geometry, netlogo, distance

I'm struggling with netlogo to measure the distance between patches in a circle. I am doing an experiment on how ant colony size impacts the size of the wall. Yellow patches represent stones from which the wall will be built.
I want to know the diameter of entrance sites (breaks in a circle). The circle(wall which the ants create) is yellow and the entrance sites are black(the entrance is in the center of the screen). How Do I check if the wall has some gaps in it. AKA if the circle is not complete and has some empty spaces where the ants can flow through.

Comment: Do you realize that it is impossible to understand your explanations ? In the first place, what are "patches in a circle" ?

Comment: Patches are a special kind of stationary agents in NetLogo that make up the world of a model. You can think of the patches as the squares that make up a chessboard. So meaning by this is that some of these patches are colored yellow, forming a circle. And there are breaks in this circle, black patches. Of which i want to know how to detect the distance between them.

Comment: It is worth to show a picture

Comment: Please copy your code in here so that we can give it a look. It is much easier to provide guidance on how to improve your code if we can see it and play around with it ourselves. Please refer to this link for how a good stackoverflow question should be structured: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like to measure the distance of the gaps in the circle. For this, you could do something like this:

```
ask patches with [pcolor = yellow] [
  let closest min-one-of other patches with [pcolor = yellow] [distance myself]
  show closest
  show distance closest
]
```

Every yellow patch will check for the closest other yellow patch. By checking which distance between yellow patches is the greatest, you can find out where in the circle the gap is the greatest.

Right now the values are printed, but you might want to save it to a list to use for further operations.